# What's the difference between fue and estuvo

Tags: gramática

What's the difference between `fue` and `estuvo`?

They both mean `was` (past).

I know in the present, Spanish makes a difference between `ser = to be` (permanent) and `estar = to be` (temporary).

- `fue` comes from `ser`.
- `estuvo` comes from `estar`.

`fue` and `estuvo` referring to something that happened in a specific moment of the past.

If you wanted to refer to something that happened regularly in the past, you would use:

- `era` for `ser`
- `estaba` for `estar`.

Despite knowing this, I don't fully understand the difference between `fue` and `estuvo`? When would you use one and not the other?

Thanks!

Comment: `era` and `fue` provide different context: you would say `Bush fue presidente de EE.UU. entre 2000 y 2008`, as well as `Bush era el presidente de EE.UU. en 2004`. Then,  for `estuvo`, say `Bush estuvo de presidente EE.U.. entre 2000 y 2008`.

Comment: @fedorqui just to double check how does `era`  and `fue` change the meaning in the examples you posted? they seem to be the same to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If you wanted to refer to something that happened regularly in the past, you would use:
>
> **era** for ser
>
> **estaba** for estar.

Well, I don't think that you would use one over the other in order *to refer to something that happened regularly in the past*. You use one over the other regarding the nature of the event.

For example, you say "estar enfadado" and not "ser enfadado". Thus, to describe that someone was "regularly upset in the past"

> Mi abuelo **estaba** siempre enfadado. Mi abuelo estaba siempre fumando
>
> El hotel estaba siempre lleno en verano, porque era cuando todo el mundo tenía vacaciones

On the contrary, you say that someone "es amable" not "está amable", so to convey that someone "was regularly kind (when you saw him/her)":

> Mi abuelo **era** siempre muy amable cada vez que íbamos a visitarle
>
> Cristina era elegida "reina del baile" todos los veranos (You say someone **is** rey/reina del baile, not that someone *estaba* reina del baile)

So I think that you had a great idea considering that

> **fue** comes from **ser**.
>
> **estuvo** comes from **estar**.

That could be a good rule of thumb to tell between using one or the other. If you were going to say the same thing but using a present simple tense, would you use `ser`? Then pick `fue`. Would you use `estar`? the pick `estaba`.